# Calling a Python function from a collection of files containing functions

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a project where users can define functions (to do things to a Redis DB, though it probably doesn't matter) in a file. These files will live in a folder with lots of other similar files. Think of building a library of functions that act on a Redis db like custom Redis commands. It might be something similar to `homebrew` as far as the ability to add new functions.

As it is currently written, the person using the script will provide a string representation of the function they want to run and the script will find it and run it. I'd like for the main script to be able to walk the files in this library directory and make all of the functions in each file available to the main script.

I know how to call a function from a string of the function name. What I cannot figure out is how to walk the files in this directory and `import` the functions or make the functions available to be called.

Right now, I only have it working with functions defined in the main script using code like this where `command` is a string of a function name passed from the command line:

```
possibles = globals().copy()
possibles.update(locals())
custom_method = possibles.get(command)
if custom_method:
    print custom_method(r)
```

There are some other questions in my head here like maybe I should force all library methods to live in a class with the same name of the file? Would that, or something similar, make what I'm trying to do easier? Maybe the `imp` module and `find_module` can help?

A follower on Twitter proposed this solution: https://gist.github.com/1853553

Comment: "provide a string representation of the function they want to run and the script will find it and run it."  Why?  Why not just import and name the function without resorting to a string representation?  `from library.filename import function` and then just use the function.  Why mess with string versions of function names?

Comment: @S.Lott Because this is a command-line app where the user is doing something like:

`> mytool custom_command "custom arguments"`

And that `custom_command` bit is the name of the function I have to find and then run.

Comment: Why not simply do this from the `>>>` prompt in Python?  You can assure a default import (using the customization hooks in http://docs.python.org/library/site.html).  Then they can simply type `mytool( custom_command( custom arguments ) )` with zero overheads or extra processing.

Comment: Because this is not designed for Python users. It's a tool I'm building for end users who know the command line but don't know anything about Python or Redis. Basically, people who need to run a bunch of custom redis commands and do analysis on the results sometimes in an automated way.

Comment: They don't need to know Python.  The syntax is almost exactly like yours but with ()'s.  You can provide an environment in which they can simply type commands that (secretly) are classes or functions you've defined for them.

Comment: @S.Lott: the command line has its advantages over the Python interpreter (filename completion, command history). Also, I can imagine entering the Python interpreter can be psychological barrier to non-programmers.

Comment: I believe filename completion, command history and the like are available through the http://docs.python.org/library/rlcompleter.html module.  I believe that any command-line `>>>` prompt has precisely equal psychological barriers.  They don't need to **know** it's Python.  It's a very rich environment that already does most of what you want.  It reduces your development cost and risk to use a proven, existing solution.  And.  You gain features for no work simply by disclosing that it's just Python to the power users.

Comment: @S.Lott I definitely see your point and in my work environment, it would make great sense. However, as I was originally working on this to make it open-source, I really wanted to keep it on the command-line. Your suggestion does make things much easier. Thanks for talking (typing?) through it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [importlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html) module is what you're looking for along with `os` and `os.path`

Once you get the files loaded up, you can use  the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module and/or `dir()` to build up a list of available functions/classes/etc.